# java.lang.NullPointerException at impl.org.controlsfx.skin.PopOverSkin.lambda$new$68(PopOverSkin.java:255)

Tags: java, javafx, popover

This error occures when popover of ControlFx is moved. Google doesn't return any result when it is searched.
Anyone knows what is the reason.

Here is the full stack trace of error.

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at impl.org.controlsfx.skin.PopOverSkin.lambda$new$68(PopOverSkin.java:255)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$48(GtkApplication.java:139)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: what is `PopOverSkin.java:255` on this line?

Comment: It is class from impl.org.controlsfx.skin package of Controlfx.jar

Comment: @Jens marked it as duplicate but it is not so. That answer does not contain the answer I want

Comment: @Azhar But that is the best answer you can get without showing your code

Comment: If you only give basic details then you can only expect a basic answer. The best thing you can do is try debugging.

Comment: @Jens issue is in this class PopOverSkin.java:255 but it is in jar. This error happens when popover is moved.

Comment: @BenThurley we can't debug in class file right

Comment: @Azhar you can debug any class, you just need the source attached. If you debug a maven project in eclipse it will automatically download the source.

Comment: Thanks @BenThurley